# Change CSS pending if else of class

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I'm trying to change the css of one div element is another div element has a selective class

```
$( function(){
if ($('nav .mobile-link').hasClass('active')){
    $('section .mobile').css("background","yellow");
}else{}

});
```

Comment: and it doesn't work... why? maybe change to `background-color`

Comment: Ya so? Can you describe the issue or we have to figure that out ourselves?

Comment: @cr0ss And you are wrong, background is a short hand valid syntax

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle

Comment: @Mr.Alien I know. But there's just not enough information there. Shooting in the dark

Comment: JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/5t29A/

Comment: you are adding the class at runtime, and you're executing the code when the page is loaded. Meaning your code runs only once, not every time someone presses the button to add the `active` class

Comment: How would you change it then?

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5t29A/3/ but I'm not sure how your website should work either. This is just a pointer. Right now one can click on the three links and keep them all active. Is that what you really need? Or only one can be active at any given time?

Comment: Nope that is perfect. It is essentially a filter to filter out all non-highlighted elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function separately to check if the `div` has the `active` class attached.

Something like this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5t29A/3/)**:

```
function checkColor(){
    if ($('nav div.mobile-link').hasClass('active')) {
        $('section div.mobile').css("background", "yellow");
    } else {
        $('section div.mobile').css("background", "#ccc");
    }
}
```

You still need to figure out the flow and events of your website to make it work.